# Pinning other applications as device owner

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-screen-pinning

My application is already device owner and I can pin my own activities without user interaction. But now I want other (legacy) apps to be pinned through my service.

Is this possible at all?

What I've tried:

- Starting my own 'launcher' app first and let that activity start the other application: nothing happens (the log tells me: "startActivityUnchecked: Attempt to violate Lock Task Mode")
- Calling the 'startLockTaskCurrent' on the internal activity manager (using a binder). This results in a missing permission "android.permission.MANAGE_ACTIVITY_STACKS" with a SecurityException. This permission is internal and only available for system apps (which I am not and will not easily be).

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

You only have the option to use `mDPM.setLockTaskPackages("com.foo.myapp");` inside your app and the other app can afterwards make use of the `startLockTask();` method.

Comment: what do u mean when you say other apps can afterwards make use of startLockTask()?...how?device owner app will be pinned. how does the other app come into picture.can anybody please explain.